# Intl is not defined firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, internationalization, ecmascript-intl

I have following java scripts code which runing well in chrome but fail in firefox and IE.
the error message of FF is 'ReferenceError: Intl is not defined'
the error message of IE is 'SCRIPT5009: 'Intl' is undefined '

```
<script>
var co = new Intl.Collator('pinyin');
console.log(co);
var co = new Intl.Collator('zh-Hans');
console.log(co);
var co = new Intl.Collator('zh-Hans-CN');
console.log(co);
</script>
```

I just wonder why the standard object Intl can't be refer in FF or IE? did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a new API that's not supported by Firefox (as of the date of this writing).

See [the MDN page and its section about browser support for the feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Browser_Compatibility).

Note that it's also unsupported by IE prior to IE 11, and it's unsupported by desktop and iOS Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current status of Intl support:

http://mihai-nita.net/2013/07/28/javascript-internationalization-api/