# Angular 2 - 'Intl' is undefined in IE 9

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to run an angular 2 app in IE 9, however I'm getting the following error:

Unhandled Promise rejection: 'Intl' is undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intl is not defined firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128836/intl-is-not-defined-firefox)

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: You can attempt to use an intl browser polyfill such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl

Comment: Having the same issue in ie10